# How can I create Infinite Scrolling in UICollectionView for iOS Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, infinite-scroll

How To Create Infinite Scrolling in my `UICollectionView`?

attached screenshot :

[image]

Now my `NSArray` is

```
NSArray* nameArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];
```

**I want to create an Infinite Scrolling in collectionView After Complete array repeat all cells again and again.**

**Left and Right both side required to scroll Infinite.**

If yes, then how can I implement please give a reference in objective-c.

Thanks!!! In advance

Comment: You can achieve it with UIPageViewController but I don't think you can achieve it with UICollectionViewController

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Please give instruction or reference how can i do this? If you have more idea regarding infinite Scrolling then let me know.

Comment: But Now I required to implement with UICollectionView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162417/discussion-between-chandresh-kachariya-and-sandeep-bhandari).

Comment: Simple google search for `uicollectionview infinite scrolling` shows many, many results with how-tos, tutorials, examples, etc....

Comment: There are different ways but the simplest is to duplicate the data at each end so create an array like this `[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"4" @"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"0", nil]` and then using the scroll view methods of your delegate detect when you get to each end and move to the other end.  So when you get to the '0' at the right you move to the '0' at the second position.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is using [StableCollectionViewLayout](https://github.com/aimalygin/StableCollectionViewLayout).

The basic principle of implementation is creating a subclass of UICollectionViewLayout and overriding these methods

```
override open func prepare(forCollectionViewUpdates updateItems: [UICollectionViewUpdateItem]) {
    super.prepare(forCollectionViewUpdates: updateItems)

    // there is possible to calculate a content offset the difference
    // with the help layout attributes for each updated item or only visible items
    self.offset = calculate(...)
}

override open func finalizeCollectionViewUpdates() {
    super.finalizeCollectionViewUpdates()
    self.offset = nil
}

override open func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    // there is necessary to add difference to/instead proposedContentOffset
    if let offset = self.offset {
       return offset
    }
    return proposedContentOffset
}
```

It allows keeping content offset when inserting or deleting happens.
Then you can just insert at the head and delete the tail, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

First thing replace your current NSArray with NSMutableArray and make this changes as above in your cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return nameArr.count;
}

- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     UILabel *label = [cell viewWithTag:25];
     [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];

     if(indexPath.row == nameArr.count-1) {
        [nameArr addObjectsFromArray:nameArr.mutableCopy];
        [collectionView reloadData];
     }
     return cell;
}
```

Here we are adding the same array objects again and again so it will be scroll infinite time.
Attached screenshot: [Refer This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn879.png)

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is use for only right to left  Infinite Scrolling, Not left to right scroll.

Comment: I Like this type of infinite scrolling in objective c. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hfswipeview

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and i solved it by returning the number of items 
 in numberOfItemsInSection: by 2

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return _array.count * 2;
}
```

in cellForItemAtIndexPath i return the cell the usual way and if the index is higher than the _array.count the just subtract the _array.count from the index.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView 
*)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSInteger index = indexPath.item;
    if(index > _array.count - 1){
        index -= _array.count;
    }
    CellView *cell = [collectionView 
        dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" 
        forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //To get the string from the array use
    NSString string = [_array objectAtIndex:(index % _array.count)];
    return cell;
}
```

Now the thing about this method is that i use only 2N items in the collectionView instead of a huge random number.

The trick is "put the 2 arrays side by side" and to keep the user in the middle using the offset.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    int scrollViewWidth = scrollView.contentSize.width;

    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    if(offset.x < scrollViewWidth /4){
        offset.x += scrollViewWidth / 2;
        [scrollView setContentOffset:offset];
    } else if(offset.x > scrollViewWidth /4 *3){
        offset.x -= scrollViewWidth / 2;
        [scrollView setContentOffset:offset];
    }
}
```