# Int max crashing when trying to set numberOfItemsInSection for collection View circular scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4

Currently, I am having 3 cell in my collection view I want rotation like after 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1  in both direction. so the user can scroll in both directions. And to achieve this I am returning Int.max in numberOfItemsInSection

```
var max = Int.max
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return max
}
```

But App is crashing with no logs in console.
If I give it a really log value like 10K something it's working. Can someone tells me why it's crashing (using iPhone 6 to run the code)

```
print(max) //9223372036854775807 log
```

cellForItemAt indexPath is not a problem because code stops at numberOfItemsInSection and never reach at cellForItemAt. still below is the code for cellForItemAt indexPath

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let itemToShow = viewControllers[indexPath.row % viewControllers.count]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SwipeTabCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeTabCollectionViewCell
    cell.title.text = itemToShow
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Don't use max...just use some number like 100 and keep insert more value when the scrollview reached middle point or so

Comment: here is a pod that could help you: https://cocoapods.org/pods/PMCircularCollectionView

Comment: @Tj3n I liked your approach and doing this func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.item == (max/2)  {
            max  = max * 2
            tabBarCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    } . 
but after max become 20 from 10 (10* 2) cellForItemAt calling only three times stop calling even after I swipe

Comment: ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this and works for me. Change max to a let or just use the code below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Int.max
}
```

Comment: At first, I was doing this only but no luck it crashes maybe its OS or architecture related Int are treated differently in different architecture maybe

Comment: take a look at the first answere from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076430/how-can-i-create-infinite-scrolling-in-uicollectionview-for-ios-objective-c  it uses a nice trick on scrollView