# Automatically making UICollectionview scrolling horizontally

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm setting a collection view, which contains many cells, and already scrolls horizontally, to scroll automatically through each cell, what i have discovered till now, that its done by using a timer, but what should be done to make the collection view move? and when reaching last cell, start again from the first cell.

i tried:

```
-(void)fireAlert {
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(scrollCollectionView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[timer fire];

}

-(void)scrollCollectionView{// cell index for testing, its 0 at the beginning.
self.cellIndex = self.cellIndex + 1;
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:5 inSection:0]
                            atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom
                                    animated:YES];
   }
```

but didn't work

other code if useful:

```
-(void)setCollectionView {
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
[self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self setCollectionViewCell];
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}



-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   // filling the cells
return cell;
}

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return CGSizeMake(150, self.collectionView.frame.size.height);

}

-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076430/how-can-i-create-infinite-scrolling-in-uicollectionview-for-ios-objective-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create Infinite Scrolling in UICollectionView for iOS Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076430/how-can-i-create-infinite-scrolling-in-uicollectionview-for-ios-objective-c)

Comment: the library used is not working

Comment: not working means..? Can you elaborate more please ?

Comment: i got 11 errors in the library files after installing the library

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `GitHub` repo below. On the other hand, this was written in `Swift` so make sure that you have to convert the code into `Objective C`.

https://github.com/rmurdoch/Infinite-Auto-Scroll-UICollectionView